# Example of a continuous function so that $v^2$ subharmonic and $v$ not subharmonic

Tags: complex-analysis, continuity

I am trying to find an example of a continuous function $v:U(0,1)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ so that $v^2$ is subharmonic, but $v$ is not. I can't seem to find a match that satisfies both criteria,therefore some hints would really help me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The condition that a function $v^2(x)$ is subharmonic in a one-dimensional domain is that

$$\partial_x^2 v^2(x) \ge 0$$.

Hence, the requirement that $v^2(x)$ is subharmonic but that $v(x)$ is not is

$$(v'(x))^2 + v(x) v''(x) \ge 0$$

on the whole domain but

$$v''(x)<0$$

at some point on the domain.

We could then choose something that satisfies the second criterion everywhere:

$$v(x) = - x^2 +b x +c $$

Then, $$ \partial_x^2 v^2(x) = -4c(1+b)+12x^2$$

so choosing $c=-1,b=0$ would seem to give us a function that was subharmonic nowhere in $\mathbb{R}$ and whose square was subharmonic everywhere. And it's continuous, of course:

$$f(x) = -x^2 -1$$.